# How to configure basic authentication in Apache httpd virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, httpd, mercurial, http-authentication

I'm trying to configure mercurial access using Apache http.
It requires authentication. My `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mercurial` looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAdmin  webmaster@localhost
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^(.*) /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hgwebdir.cgi/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Every tutorial I read on the internet tells me to insert these lines:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/httpd/users
```

But when I do it I get the following error:

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mercurial:
AuthType not allowed here
```

My distro is a customized Ubuntu called Turnkey Linux Redmine

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should place this inside a Location directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

<Location /> #the / has to be there, otherwise Apache startup fails
            Deny from all
            #Allow from (You may set IP here / to access without password)
            AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/httpd/users
            AuthName authorization
            AuthType Basic
            Satisfy Any # (or all, if IPs specified and require IP + pass)
                        # any means neither ip nor pass
            require valid-user
</Location>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: this does not work for me. `<Location /opt/mcmap/shapefiles.php>
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName KerberosLogin
        KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet.spectrumasa.com
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd On
        KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.COM
        Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/intranet.keytab
        require valid-user
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Location>`

Comment: The apache doc page explains all this, but annoyingly never gives you a complete example. I copied part of their example, but missed the `require valid-user` portion. A complete example can be a wonderful thing. Thanks.

Comment: @sharif should be <Location />, meaning access to the root url of yourhost.com/ should require that auth configuration

Comment: I needed `<Location />` in any case to not get a syntax error when loading the config file.

Comment: Why was `<Location />`  edited to `<Location>` with an internal log message of "fixed ... to avoid a lot of trouble", but telling nothing about the real reason in the answer itself? There is no such thing as a `<Location>` directive (i.e. one *without* a location) in Apache. *That* definitely causes trouble now. ;) (See e.g. above.)

Comment: This answer contains an annoying mix of old and new directives. Remove the `Deny from all` and `Satisfy Any` and disable the module `mod_access_compat` for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 11):

I am running Apache2 on ubuntu 10.04 — same problem and thanks for the solution. I found that I had to put the configuration in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

You can generate the username and password using htpasswd. New file:

```
$ htpasswd -c /srv/auth/.htpasswd squire
```

To append to existing file:

```
$ htpasswd -b /srv/auth/.htpasswd squire2 tickleme2
```

Answer (score 8):

You can protect a Location or a Directory. For a Directory add something like:

```
<Directory /some/dir/cgi-bin/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName 'Private scripts'
    AuthUserFile '/some/other/dir/.htpasswd'
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

You can also add `Deny` and `Allow` directives for a finer control.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're specifying the authentication settings within the `VirtualHost`.  Typically, these settings are specified under the `Directory` directive.

You could also use `.htaccesss` files, but specifying in the Apache conf is a good default, as it has less exposure.

[Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Apache2 on ubuntu 10.10. I've been having problems with all the solutions above, but this worked well (from apache docs):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /etc/users
  Require user visitor
</Directory>
```

The biggest difference from the answers above seems to be the AuthBasicProvider directive set to "file" and the Require directive including the "user" bit before the actual username.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

We are running a memory optimised version of apache, and encountered this problem.

This was due to the following line not being present in the apache configuration:

```
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
```